# Symfony validate entity using form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

```
    $userData = (new User())
        ->setPersonCode(123)
        ->setPhone('+470002342342342');

    $userForm = $this->toolbar->getForm(UserType::class, $userData);
```

I'm creating form from entity class where is setted data. If now I try use:

```
$userForm->isValid();
```

I'm getting `true`, because form data is not submitted, how I can do validation, without setting manually data to form and submitting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to submit data to a form, skip forms entirely; use the [Validator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html) service directly:

```
<?php

// (Assuming you're in a controller, otherwise inject the validator some other way.)

$userData = (new User())
    ->setPersonCode(123)
    ->setPhone('+470002342342342');

$validator = $this->get('validator');
$errors    = $validator->validate($userData);
$isValid   = count($errors) === 0;
```

Comment: can I use in validator `Assert\IsTrue` annotations ?

Comment: If you've set those on the Model class you feed to the `validate` function, they will be recognized, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is worded a little strange and im not sure exactly what you want, If you want to manually set the data like above then call $form->submit() passing the user data.

```
$userData = (new User())
    ->setPersonCode(123)
    ->setPhone('+470002342342342');

$userForm = $this->toolbar->getForm(UserType::class);
$userForm->submit($userData);
if(!$userForm->isValid()){
    // handle errors
}
```

If you want to have the user submit data on a form then do something like this:

```
public function createUserAction(Request $request)
{
    $userForm = $this->toolbar->getForm(UserType::class);
    $userForm->handleRequest();
    if(!$userForm->isValid()){
        // handle errors
    }
}
```

`$userForm->handleRequest();` will handle taking data that was submitted from the form on the page.

Comment: How I can call `$form->sumbit() ` ? I not have data array.

Comment: @Wizard where are you expecting data to come from then? If its the form, use the second method